# Why is IIS w3wp.exe spawning processes like netstat or nslookup, powershell, etc

Tags: iis, w3wp

Has anyone seen anything like this I am trying to chase down. IIS w3wp.exe is spawning processes, is this a particular feature in iis or logging etc?

Command Line

```
"cmd.exe" /c cmd.exe /c nslookup example-domain-name.com
```

InitiatingFileName
w3wp.exe

InitCommand Line

```
w3wp.exe -ap "APPNAME" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \\.\pipe\iisipm..[CUT]... -h "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\APPNAME\APPNAME.config" -w "" -m 0 -t 20 -ta 0
```

I can't find why it is doing this in the logs, and wondering if it is a misconfig or an iis feature to log this activity.

Comment: What kind of web application is being hosted on IIS? The behavior you observed (shell out to cmd.exe) is rather strange and not part of IIS itself (IIS consumes native Windows API so no need to shell out). You'd better review the source code of the web application to learn more.

Comment: Ya, thanks. Most of what we see is internal commands and nothing abnormal but the logging itself. Nothing in the code is producing it. Doing some research the output from w3wp is being logged. But unsure how the logs are getting created and Sentinel is picking them up only on a few servers. 

https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Identifying-Worker-Process-w3wp-exe-to-relevant-application-pool-via-command-line?language=en_US

 https://abhijitjana.net/2010/11/04/how-to-use-iis-manager-to-get-worker-processes-w3wp-exe-details-information/

Comment: If possible, you can open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to consult Microsoft support directly. They can provide you action plans to investigate further on the source of such behaviors.

Comment: Think we found the source, looks like these servers have dynatrace installed on them.

Comment: Then you can post your own answer below. The way you found out the source might help others in the future.